# Using EF 6.4 with Core 3.1 (blazor) - does it work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an old solution using EF, and I would like to upgrade my presentation project to core 3.1 in order to use blazor. I would like to keep using EF, so I have upgraded to 6.4.

I did read some news about EF 6.4 being supported in .NET Core, but I'm struggling to make it work.

All my projects are standard 2.1, except my .NET Core 3.1 project. I am able to build the projects, but I'm not able to add the context to startup.

I've tried the following:

```
public class MyCustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyCustomDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<MyCustomDbContext>(_ => new MyCustomDbContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Error:

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'Core.Entities'. Ensure that you're
>   using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor
>   generic.

Comment: Did you try overriding `OnConfiguring` method in your context, too ?!

Answer (score 0):

You project configuration is all good.

The error you are seeing is caused by trying to (automatically) run migrations om a project that does not have a DbContext.

The startup project runs the migrations, but the DbContext is in another project.

To configure EF to target the project containing the DbContext, add a migration like this:

> Add-Migration EmptyMigration -ProjectName "Core.Entities" -StartUpProjectName "Core.Presentation"

Where Core.Entities is the project containing the DbContext, and Core.Presentation is your startup project.

Comment: mmm does he have migrations enabled. and remember this is Framework not core.

Comment: @Seabizkit It seams to me that this is about EF 6.4 targeting .NET Standard, not .NET Framework. This is the only way I could reproduce this specific error message.

Comment: Sorry your right that's not what i meant but can totally see why you say that, what i was trying to say is that this is EF 6 and not Core, your answer 100% applies to ef-core, but only 50% to ef-6 and was just saying they these a chance that this is not what is doing on... here.

Comment: @Seabizkit I am not sure what you mean. `Add-Migration` applies to EF6 [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#generating--running-migrations). 
But you are right ofcourse that it may not be the cause of the problem, even though it was the cause of the problem when I tried to reproduce it.